# logging specific package's messages to one file in grails and log4j

Tags: grails, log4j

trying to get all of the log statements from class GetThatDataFilters to go to the rolling file 'dailydata' and everything else to the console and the daily rolling file.

dont know if I am missing something from the grails documentation http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging

```
// ============================================================================
// log4j configuration
//============================================================================
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
    // appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n')

        //daily rolling log
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: 'daily', datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n'),
                file: 'logs/daily.log')

        //daily search rolling log
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: 'dailydata', datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n'),
                file: 'logs/daily-data.log')

    }


    error dailysearch: "GetThatDataFilters"

    root {
        error 'stdout', 'daily'
        additivity = true
    }

    debug 'grails.app'
}
```

Comment: I've tried the same thing before and failed just as you have and am beginning to think it's not possible using the log4j DSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    error dailydata: "GetThatDataFilters", additivity: false


    root {
        error 'stdout', 'daily'
        additivity = true
    }

    debug 'grails.app'
```